Is it possible to pass data to Google Play In-App Reviews API
I'm using Google Play In-App Reviews API to get the user to provide a review for my app. Currently, I want to have a dialog to ask the user if they want to provide a review, then prompt them to select how many stars and optional message. Is it then possible to pass this data into the review in playstore?
Picture 1
For example, this is my dialog in my app, I then want to transfer the data into the google play review in Picture 2
Picture 2
  private static void getReviewInfo() {
        ReviewManager reviewManager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(activity);
        reviewManager.requestReviewFlow().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                reviewManager.launchReviewFlow(activity, task.getResult());
            }
        });
    }

This function is used to display the review prompt like in Picture 2
Is this possible with this api?

Notice that in the documentation : "Note: The ReviewInfo object is only valid for a limited amount of time. Your app should request a ReviewInfo object ahead of time (pre-cache) but only once you are certain that your app will launch the in-app review flow." Reference
